# CMake Error at vision_visp/visp_bridge/CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I tried the following command to install [vision_visp](https://github.com/lagadic/vision_visp)

```
git clone -b kinetic-devel  https://github.com/lagadic/vision_visp.git
```

However, I am not sure that why I am getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at vision_visp/visp_bridge/CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindVISP.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "VISP", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "VISP" with any of
  the following names:

        VISPConfig.cmake
    visp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "VISP" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "VISP_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "VISP"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/akumar/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/akumar/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Can anyone help me please to solve this error? I am using ROS Noetic in Ubuntu 20.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407369/cmake-error-at-vision_visp/visp_bridge/cmakelists.txt:16-(find_package):/) by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2022-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are following two ways to install `vision_visp`:

1. **Install using `apt`:** I prefer this option as it takes care of installing dependencies and takes less time. Please use the following command:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-vision-visp
   ```
2. **Install from source:** This definitely takes a considerable amount of time to compile. Furthermore, all the dependencies must be installed before compilation. Please see below for more details:

   ```
   ravi@dell:~/ros_ws$ source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash

   ravi@dell:~/ros_ws$ git clone --branch noetic git@github.com:lagadic/vision_visp.git

   ravi@dell:~/ros_ws$ sudo rosdep init

   ravi@dell:~/ros_ws$ rosdep update

   ravi@dell:~/ros_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro noetic
   executing command [sudo -H apt-get install libdmtx-dev]
   executing command [sudo -H apt-get install ros-noetic-visp]
   executing command [sudo -H apt-get install libzbar-dev]

   ravi@dell:~/ros_ws$ catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
   ```

   You can notice that we have quite a few dependencies to build this package!

Finally, the above steps are taken from [the wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_visp) and confirmed on my machine (ROS Noetic in Ubuntu 20.04)

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on 2022-10-05**:
Thank you for your response, I will try to install everything using apt command as it is recommended.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-05**:
Please, let me know if the problem persists.  Furthermore, please upvote and mark this answer as correct in order to tag your question as answered.

**Comment by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on 2022-10-05**:
Thank you, the following error has been, resolved.